# Pin certificates throw exception only one time in Android

Tags: android, https, proxy, ssl-certificate, certificate-pinning

I try to implement pin certificate in Android project using the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#CertificatePinning).
I generated SHA-256 pin from some web-site. I set up configuration file:

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">livejournal.com</domain>
        <pin-set>
            <pin digest="SHA-256">QNT9njQO9Lij9JNvWyLRP6cjCJ2bJiPV+t7D9U9aa1Q=</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml I've added it using:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

I added simple request to the server using **HttpsURLConnection**

```
fun connect() {
        try {
            val mURL = URL("https://www.livejournal.com/")
            with(mURL.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection) {
                requestMethod = "GET"
                println("Response Code: ${this.responseCode}")
            }

        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            println(e)
        }
    }
```

I configured [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) and in the Android phone I set up proxy server. In the result, I see all https request from my browser.

In the mobile app, when I execute first request, I got the error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

But when I execute the same request second time and more I get success result.

```
Response Code: 200
```

At the same time, when I disconnect and connect to the network with proxy, I'm again getting error first time, but the next time I'm getting success result.

**Why is it happened? What is wrong and how does it work in the Android?**

Comment: Do you see the second request/response in mitmproxy that returns HTTP 200? Even without pinning you you should not see requests from the app in mitmproxy, as the installed mitmproxy certificate is a user certificate and thus is not trusted by apps (unless you configure user certs to be trusted in your networkSecurityConfig).

Comment: @Robert, I don't see also the first request in mitmproxy. Until I haven't add next configuration.

`<debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>`

Only in this case I see that the PIN is different that I expect.